# Проверить неопределенное количество элементов

Tags: python

Начинаю изучать питон
Есть функция

```
def stop_came(self):    
    win_combi = self.win_combinations()
     for each in win_combi:         
        if self.strs[each[0]] == self.strs[each[1]] == self.strs[each[2]] == self.strs[each[3]]:             
           return self.strs[each[0]]    
    return False
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что элементов self.strs[each[0]] может быть и 5, и 6 и т.д.
Как в этой строке
if self.strs[each[0]] == self.strs[each[1]] == self.strs[each[2]] == self.strs[each[3]]
сделать проверку всех элементов?

Comment: `len(set(self.strs[i] for i in each)) == 1` если `self.strs[i]` подходящего типа - строка, кортеж.

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def stop_came(it):

    if not it:
        # Возвращаем значение если условный список пуст
        return False

    first, *others = it

    if not others:
        # Возвращаем значение если условный список имеет один элемент
        return True

    return all([item == first for item in others])


list_a = [2, 2, 2, 2]
list_b = [11, 11, 11, 12, 14]
list_c = [6, 6]


print(stop_came(list_a))
# True

print(stop_came(list_b))
# False

print(stop_came(list_c))
# True
```

Comment: Блок `if not others:` не нужен.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Я без понятия как ТС интерпретирует наличие единственного элемента в списке, поэтому добавил

Comment: Я имел ввиду что это этот оператор никак не влияет на результат работы функции. Он - лишний.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, )) я имел ввиду, что если вдруг понадобится как-то по другому обработать список с едиственным элементом, то это можно сделать там ))))

Answer (score 0):

Перепишем `stop_came` с использованием функции `unambiguous`:

```
def stop_came(self):    
    win_combi = self.win_combinations()
    for each in win_combi:         
        if unambiguous(self.strs[i] for i in each):             
           return self.strs[each[0]]    
    return False
```

Если `self.strs[i]` хешируются (строки, числа, кортежи), `unambiguous` может быть такой:

```
def unambiguous(seq):
    return len(set(seq)) <= 1
```

Если хешировать нельзя, код будет сложнее:

```
def unambiguous(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    first = next(it, None)
    return all(v == first for v in it)
```

**P.S.** Оба варианта возвращают истину если в последовательности все значения равны или последовательность пуста.